# EventSource error on each connection close

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events, puma

Experimenting with Rails+SSE on a PoC application I'm getting a weird behavior. The message is successfully sent to JS, but at the same time the `error` handler is called:

[image: Google Chrome Web Inspector Console]

I have Rails 6 with the following controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def index_stream
    # SSE expects the `text/event-stream` content type
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

    # last_updated = User.last_updated.first
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream)
    sse.write(name: 'John')
  ensure
    sse.close
  end
end
```

`config.allow_concurrency = true` for `development.rb`. Using `puma` as a web server.

JS code:

```
var source = new EventSource('/user_stream');

source.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message: ', e);
  document.getElementById('users').append(e.data);
};

source.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log('Error:', e);
};
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
ETag: W/"566367df563a9487c3b0707958010517"
Set-Cookie: _sse_demo_session=WOvy%2Bknjwq%2FZzuDQQl5lTRV96Glvhe%2FdGCaIkkokzGZNpIdobigxIyVaIozYMnY70aB9RcH2muN11xPE0r%2BZ%2F8E95m9sGMNKMyu4LgVC%2BtH1b8FxHHqSkuLA0QIoc4M3VfxWjLZkSrSg9OL5edo2kKGnW0x2R70itcwvq5d62RE%2BzQHSFHT%2FBF%2F32zWb%2FgO9e1mkgI%2FFoz33c6x6zI1QftTxTe7eeFQ0CAlEDBJsTmBQ2xo8yZBlOzn0uqe66LENld1bANvCoYxTXFxZTeyWW46uv7x5lihywA%3D%3D--pgfHW6WrLuKnKnAF--idzmcsiSA8CS85mu4a4QsA%3D%3D; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 0e17b656-04d7-4c63-9ca4-d8650d0ccf96
X-Runtime: 0.028097
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Any ideas why that errors raise? The demo app can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ka8725/sse-demo) and [Heroku](https://hubstaff-sse-demo.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer on my own. According to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) it's a normal behaviour:

> When a user agent is to reestablish the connection, the user agent must run the following steps. These steps are run asynchronously, not as part of a task. (The tasks that it queues, of course, are run like normal tasks and not asynchronously.)
> Queue a task to run the following steps:
>
> 1. If the readyState attribute is set to CLOSED, abort the task.
> 2. Set the readyState attribute to CONNECTING.
> 3. Fire a simple event named error at the EventSource object.

So, it's just such a protocol.